# What is meant by the "Quran is the only book that can be memorized"

Tags: quran

I was passing by a mosque and a sign asserted that the Quran is miraculous in that it is the only book that can be memorized. I have also heard this asserted by Moslems.

Now there are several short children's books that I have memorized and the 1.6 billion Moslems aren't going to abandon their faith just because I have memorized all 7 sentences of "Caveman Dave."

So what are the details of the challenge? It should go something like this:
The Quran is the only book that is ______ long and _____ complicated that can be memorized.

Comment: I have never heard such a claim before, despite being a Muslim my entire life. Please include a picture of the sign and I can try to interpret its meaning further.

Comment: Yeah the claim would be related to the holy book I guess as other holy books are in moderated versions and you would not be able to find the memorizer in huge nos as muslims are memorizing the Holy Quran despite of the fact that whatever the language they speak they are memorizing it in Arabic Language as it was revealed not in english or other language whether they understand Arabic or not.

Comment: I've never heard of such a claim - it seems a bit bizarre; what I have heard hat it is sunnat to memorise it; most muslims memorise a few verses neccessaary for namaz/salat; there's an art to qu'ranic recitation, like pretty much all liturgies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about the behavior of a specific group and not a canonical Islamic belief. It can perhaps only be answered by the one who wrote the sign, and others can only speculate and give personal opinions about the context and meaning. The Quran obviously isn't the only book that can be memorized, even in the Islamic tradition, hadith and other texts were memorized.

Answer (score 0):

I think this had been badly translated from the vrese "Surely We, Ever We, have been sending down the Remembrance, and surely We are indeed Preservers of it." Alhijr-9
It means that Quran is the only holy book that god promise to preserve from any corruption or change overtime.

Comment: But if a bad translation was allowed to appear on a mosque, then God hasn't protected it from corruption! There must be a different source.

Comment: It's a translation.. Not the original verse..